# Print the value of a selected cell from a datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to extract the value of a selected cell instead of its row and column coordinates when I click on it as I want to use it as input for another procedure.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data("mtcars")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable"),
    verbatimTextOutput("selectedCells")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$myDatatable <- DT::renderDataTable(mtcars, 
                                            selection=list(mode="single", target="cell"),
                                            server = FALSE,
                                            rownames=FALSE)

  output$selectedCells <- renderPrint(input$myDatatable_cells_selected)
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value in the table with row and column number like the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data("mtcars")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable"),
    verbatimTextOutput("selectedCells")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$myDatatable <- DT::renderDataTable(
        mtcars,
        selection = list(mode = "single", target =
                             "cell"),
        server = FALSE,
        rownames = FALSE
    )

    output$selectedCells <- renderPrint({
        s = input$myDatatable_cells_selected
        if (!is.null(s) && ncol(s) != 0) {
            mtcars[s[1, 1] , s[1, 2] + 1]
        } else {
            NULL
        }
    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see, one must be added to column value to specify appropriate position. Handling unselected case is also important.